# convert UTF-16LE to UTF-8 with iconv()

Tags: c, linux, iconv

I`m trying to convert UTF-16LE to UTF-8 with iconv() in Linux.

and i think it done..

But i got some trouble.. with my code..

and i think two codes are same, but first one not working. only second one working.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "iconv.h"
#include "errno.h"
#if 1
int fn2Utf8(char inBuf[], char outBuf[]) {
    size_t readBytes = sizeof(inBuf);
    size_t writeBytes = sizeof(outBuf);
    char* in = inBuf;
    char* out = outBuf;

    iconv_t convert = iconv_open("UTF-8","UTF-16LE");
    if (iconv(convert, &in, &readBytes, &out, &writeBytes) < 0) {
        return (-1);
    }
    iconv_close(convert);
    printf("[%s] [%s]\n", inBuf, outBuf);
    return (out - outBuf);
}
int main() {
    char inBuf[128] ="\x5c\x00\xbd\xac\x01\xc6\x00\xd3\x5c\x00\x00\xb3\x78\xc6\x44\xbe\x5c\x00\x2a\x00\x00\x00";
    char outBuf[128];
    fn2Utf8(inBuf, outBuf);
    return 0;
}
#else
int main() {
    char inBuf[128] = "\x5c\x00\xbd\xac\x01\xc6\x00\xd3\x5c\x00\x00\xb3\x78\xc6\x44\xbe\x5c\x00\x2a\x00\x00\x00";
    char outBuf[128];
    size_t readBytes = sizeof(inBuf);
    size_t writeBytes = sizeof(outBuf);
    char* in = inBuf;
    char* out = outBuf;

    iconv_t convert = iconv_open("UTF-8","UTF-16LE");
    if (iconv(convert, &in, &readBytes, &out, &writeBytes) < 0) {
    return (-1);
    }
    iconv_close(convert);
    printf("[%s] [%s]\n", inBuf, outBuf);
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

You can complie two type of code with if 0 -> if 1

and i need if 1 method.

Comment: Just saying "it's not working" is not a very good description of the problem. ***How*** is it not working? Doesn't it build? Do you get crashes when running? Unexpected results? Please elaborate! And please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the problem is unexpected results. and i try to read that . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
size_t readBytes = sizeof(inBuf);
size_t writeBytes = sizeof(outBuf);
```

When you pass arrays to a function, they *decay* to pointers to their first element. Your call

```
fn2Utf8(inBuf, outBuf);
```

is equal to

```
fn2Utf8(&inBuf[0], &outBuf[0]);
```

That means that in the function the arguments are not arrays, but *pointers*. And when you do `sizeof` on a pointer you get the size of the pointer and not what it's pointing to.

There are two solutions: The first is to pass in the length of the arrays as arguments to the function, and use that. The second, at least for the `inBuf` argument, is to rely on the fact that it's a null-terminated string and use `strlen` instead.

The second way, with `strlen`, works only on `inBuf` as I already said, but doesn't work on `outBuf` where you have to use the first way and pass in the size as an argument.

---

If works in the program without the function because then you are doing `sizeof` on *the array*, and not a pointer. When you have an array and not a pointer, `sizeof` will give you the size in bytes of the array.

Comment: thank you so much.

i try first method and got the answer!

fn2Utf8(inBuf, sizeof(inBuf), outBuf, sizeof(outBuf))